# Configuring Lizmap through docker compose on the server

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use this yaml taken from a git repository, suitable for testing for a production environment.

From what I understand, the connection to the Lizmap service takes place through NGINX, so I changed the port in the environment variable (before I had 127.0.0.1:8090:8080)
I simply changed 8090:80
I did the same thing for the postgis container.
-5432:5432
Currently with this configuration installed on the server I can connect from the outside and everything seems to work.
I wanted to know if the configuration is sufficient or further changes are needed for an optimized environment.
I'm also interested in knowing about the firewall:
I had tried to enable the firewall by adding a rule on port 5432 and 8090 but it seems that even regardless of the rule the ports are still open.

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  lizmap:
    image: 3liz/lizmap-web-client:${LIZMAP_VERSION_TAG}
    environment:
      LIZMAP_CACHEREDISDB: '1'
      LIZMAP_CACHEREDISHOST: redis
      LIZMAP_CACHESTORAGETYPE: redis
      LIZMAP_HOME: /srv/lizmap
      LIZMAP_USER: ${LIZMAP_UID}
      LIZMAP_WMSSERVERURL: http://map:8080/ows/
      LIZMAP_CONFIG_INCLUDE: /srv/etc
      PGSERVICEFILE: /srv/etc/pg_service.conf
      PGPASSFILE: /srv/etc/pgpass.conf
    volumes:
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_PROJECTS}", target: /srv/projects }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/var/lizmap-theme-config", target: /www/lizmap/var/lizmap-theme-config }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/var/lizmap-config", target: /www/lizmap/var/config }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/var/lizmap-db",     target: /www/lizmap/var/db }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/www", target: /www/lizmap/www }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/www/var/log", target: /www/lizmap/var/log }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/var/lizmap-modules", target: /www/lizmap/lizmap-modules }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/var/lizmap-my-packages", target: /www/lizmap/my-packages }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/etc", target: /srv/etc, read_only: true }
    command:
      - php-fpm
    depends_on:
      postgis:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: unless-stopped
  map:
    image: 3liz/qgis-map-server:${QGIS_VERSION_TAG}
    environment:
      PGSERVICEFILE: /srv/etc/pg_service.conf
      PGSPASSFILE: /srv/etc/pgpass.conf
      QGIS_OPTIONS_PATH: /srv/etc/qgis
      QGIS_SERVER_LIZMAP_REVEAL_SETTINGS: 'yes'
      QGSRV_API_ENABLED_LIZMAP: 'yes'
      QGSRV_CACHE_SIZE: '20'
      QGSRV_CACHE_STRICT_CHECK: 'no'
      QGSRV_CACHE_ROOTDIR: /srv/projects
      QGSRV_LOGGING_LEVEL: DEBUG
      QGSRV_USER: ${LIZMAP_UID}:${LIZMAP_GID}
      QGSRV_SERVER_PLUGINPATH: /srv/plugins
      QGSRV_SERVER_RESTARTMON: /srv/.qgis-restart
      QGSRV_SERVER_WORKERS: ${QGIS_MAP_WORKERS}
    volumes:
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_PROJECTS}", target: /srv/projects }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/plugins", target: /srv/plugins }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/wps-data", target: /srv/data }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/etc", target: /srv/etc, read_only: true }
    ports:
      - ${OWS_PORT}:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
  redis:
    image: redis:5-alpine
    volumes:
      - { type: volume, source: redis_data, target: /data }
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    user: ${LIZMAP_UID}:${LIZMAP_GID}
    volumes:
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/etc/nginx.conf", target: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/var/log/nginx", target: /var/log/nginx }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/var/nginx-cache", target: /var/cache/nginx }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}", target: /srv/lizmap }
    ports:
      - ${LIZMAP_PORT}:8080
    depends_on:
      - lizmap
  postgis:
    image: 3liz/postgis:${POSTGIS_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - { type: volume, source: postgis_data, target: /var/lib/postgresql/data }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/etc/postgres.init.d", target: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d }
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_LIZMAP_DB: ${POSTGRES_LIZMAP_DB}
      POSTGRES_LIZMAP_USER: ${POSTGRES_LIZMAP_USER}
      POSTGRES_LIZMAP_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_LIZMAP_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - ${POSTGIS_PORT}:5432
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres -d ${POSTGRES_LIZMAP_DB} -q || exit 1"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      start_period: 60s
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - ${POSTGIS_ALIAS}

volumes:
    postgis_data:
        driver: local
    redis_data:
        driver: local
```

I have tried changing the ports in the yml and expect to have an optimized configuration

Comment: That seems like a surprisingly large number of bind mounts for a production deployment.  Can you clarify the specific problem you're running into, and what you're trying to change?  Can you reduce the Compose file to a [mcve] that only shows the parts of the system needed to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I'm trying to understand if it is possible to improve the configuration for a production environment and how to set the firewall on the ports.